# Multiple voltage sources connected to Attiny85

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, voltage-source

I have a circuit with a Attiny85 micro controller that is powered by a solar cell and a capacitor (10F 3V8). When I want to change the code on the micro controller I have to attache a USB programmer that operates (and provides) 5V. Since the circuit will be soldered I wont be able to detach the capacitor.

My question is if it is possible to have multiple power sources in a circuit and what I should do to protect the capacitor when introducing the 5V power source to the circuit.

This is the circuit I'm talking about:
[image]

Comment: Where does the power from the USB programmer come into this circuit?  Is it after (on the cathode side) the 1N4148?

Comment: And why do you think you have to protect the capacitor?

Comment: You may find what your looking for in this post:     https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/8956/how-to-program-attiny85-running-3-3v

Comment: @SteveSh because 5v on a 3.8v capacitor is not good...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all your help. I found a solution that suits me based on your recommendations:

I use a [USBtinyISP](https://learn.adafruit.com/usbtinyisp/use-it) for programming and I can remove a jumper to prevent power delivery to the board. That means that as long as the capacitor is charged I can program the micro controller.

> USBtinyISP [..] uses a level shifter so that if the jumper is not in place, it will use whatever the target voltage is [..]

While I have the hardware on a breadboard (or capacitor is empty) I use a USB to TTL adapter for 3.3V power delivery (and as connection for the serial monitor output).

Please let me know in case you think my solution has some flaw. I don't usually work with electronics.

Answer (score 2):

Your circuit for usb programming should include a 5V to 3.3V voltage regulator. The usb data is 3.3V anyway, and you have no need for 5V on the vcc rail.

That or get a 10F 6V or higher capacitor. The voltage rating on a capacitor is not the voltage it produces. It is the voltage it can withstand before damage occurs.

Answer (score 1):

As it's a large value capacitor ie: 10 Farads and only 3.8V rating you will have to disconnect it from the circuit somehow by de-soldering if you are applying 5V from a separate source, in this case the programmer.  There is no other way around it electrically. You could put two silicon diodes in series with the 5V supplied from the programmer say another couple of 1N4148s or similar but whether this would disrupt the programmer operation would be unknown.

Comment: Desoldering would not be necessary if you plan ahead and provide another way of disconnecting the capacitor, which could be as simple as a switch or jumper.